# Kali Linux on Macbook

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, parallels-desktop

I have a question about kali linux on an Apple Macbook Pro running in Parallels.
 After giving the command `sudo airmon-ng` in terminal, it shows no interface.

Does anybody know what to do or is it not possible to successfully use kali linux in a virtual machine on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

`airmon-ng` is a part of **Aircrack-ng** and if you want to use the *Aircrack-ng software suite* in a VM you'll need to provide your own USB Wi-Fi Network Adapter attached directly to the VM since Parallels, VMware Fusion and VirtualBox, only provide a wired Ethernet adapter to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Kali Linux in a virtual machine hypervisor, such as VirtualBox, VMware, and Parallels. However, in order to connect to network interfaces - since you have mentioned the desire to use tools that require a connection to a Wi-Fi network - you will need a USB Wi-Fi adapter. I don't have much experience with Parallels, but I know that most virtual machine emulators allow you to connect other devices (again, such as an external Wi-Fi adapter). However, I know some people who have told me that plugging in such an adapter to a USB hub will cause some sort of "input error", just FYI. Also, if you are considering purchasing a Wi-Fi adapter, I would suggest one that does not require extra drivers to be installed, as that would require access to the internet. Lastly, if you are curious as to the reason why you would need to purchase a Wi-Fi adapter for your virtual machine in the first place, that is because the virtual machine is not allowed to access the host's internal Wi-Fi card, because it is a *virtual* machine and cannot interact with your computer on a hardware level unless you use something like a Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: This would be great if you could provide details how you know drivers aren’t needed for an adapter in this use case.